# Import Master Page into another Master Page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to make one master page simply include another master page?

I have three master pages, which have converged in content, and I want to make 2 of them point to the third, so that the content is not replicated, but leaving them in so that they can change easily in the future if they have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, what you need is called **nested master pages**. Just set the `MasterPageFile` in the `<%@ Master %>` directive of child master pages to the parent one.

Main.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

.... shared content ....
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="C" runat="server" />
```

First.Master:

```
<% Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Main.Master" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="C">
   .... Some content ....
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AnotherPlaceholder" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Second.Master:

```
<% Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Main.Master" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="C">
   .... Some other content ....
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="AnotherPlaceholder" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Should the ContentPlaceHolder's defined in the Main.Master page, be accesible by content pages that use First or Second.Master as their master page?

Comment: @AlexH: It won't be directly accessible. If you want to propagate it to the page: <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ID" runat="server><asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ID /></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>. A page will only see ContentPlaceHolders specified directly in its master page.